# Entity DBContext to LinQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to `Entity Framework`. Please help.

I'm getting `Stored Proc` result and binding to a `Server control` `Repeater` using Entity Framework, DBCoontext. Now with that result, I need to perform another operation, to get the count of records and assign it to a `Label`.

```
using(var DBContext = new DBEntities())
{
   Repeater.DataSource = DBContext.SP_GetRecords();                
   Repeater.DataBind();
   Label.Text = DBContext.SP_GetRecords().Count().ToString();
}
```

**Problem:** I do not want to call SP_GetRecords() again. Meaning, I didn't wanted to make an SQL call. In straight ADO.NET, we can get result in `DataTable`, bind to a control, apply `LinQ` to get the count based on some condition. Can we do same in EntityFramework?

Comment: What does "It's not working" mean?

Comment: Repeater is showing empty

Comment: I've edited the question. Please help for the unnecessary SQL DB call that I am making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if I understood the question properly, but will this do the trick for you? Do note the `ToList()` call on the fetch to be sure we enumerate just once.

```
using(var DBContext = new DBEntities())
{
   var records = DBContext.SP_GetRecords().ToList(); // Enumerate
   Repeater.DataSource = records; // will not                 
   Repeater.DataBind();
   Label.Text = records.Count().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I didnt know about ToList()

Comment: You don't need to the LINQ method `Count()` if you're explicitly casting it to list using `.ToList()`.  `.Count` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your stored procedure to a result, and then assign/do operations on it however you'd like.  I don't know what it returns (so I'll assume a list/ienumerable of some sort), but you can essentially do this:

```csharp
using(var DBContext = new DBEntities())
{
   var results = DBContext.SP_GetRecords();
   Repeater.DataSource = results;                
   Repeater.DataBind();
   Label.Text = results.Count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: we cannot do that. I had tried this earlier.. results.count will fail at compile time itself

Comment: As I said - I have no idea what your return type is. If your return type from `DBContext.SP_GetRecords()` is a type `List<T>`, then you can. Otherwise, use `Count()`